# How to remotely log in to an ubuntu server after removing Python?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

I removed python from an ubuntu server that I connect to remotely (I was trying to install a newer python version). Then, rebooted the server. Now, I am unable to login back with ssh (the server does not accept my password anymore), although I can still ping it from my system.

I read in some forums that I might need to install a new OS. However, I do need my data on the OS that I cannot access now, so it is necessary for me to log in to the server somehow. Is there any way that I can do so?

Comment: Easiest way to recover data will be to mount the disk using live media (if dealing with physical hardware) or by just mounting the disk volume in another VM if using virtualization.

Comment: Is this managed by a third party service? Removing Python shouldn't effect SSH.

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the server, attach a screen to it and try to log in to the console

If this is a shared host or virtual system, your provider should offer you some kind virutal interface to display the local console of the server.

Honestly I can't imagine why uninstalling python would break your sshd, but it is possible that another component broke and can't boot now.

But again, you would know more if you could check your console screen.